# Read /proc/net/tcp and get IP address from String

Tags: java, android

I'm reading `proc/net/tcp` file from `filereader` and parsing data from `regex` to get what need .

The example string from `proc/net/tcp` is :

`0: 0401A8C0:D366 FFB79E23:01BB 01 00000000:00000000 00:00000000 00000000 11269        0 14392479 1 00000000 30 4 30 10 -1`

So the `local address` : `port` is : `0401A8C0:D366` , i have tried convert hex to string via that method but it doesn't return valid data .... Can someone help how to read datas ?

It should give something like : `192.168.*.*` .

To parse the ip address should get bytearray from this `0401A8C0` Little Endian String , but can't solve

`The Hex to String method :`

```
public String fromHex(String hex) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
    hex = hex.replaceAll("^(00)+", "");
    byte[] bytes = new byte[hex.length() / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < hex.length(); i += 2) {
        bytes[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(hex.charAt(i), 16) << 4) + Character.digit(hex.charAt(i + 1), 16));
    }
    return new String(bytes);
}
```

Comment: What do you mean with hex to string? If you see it like that in a text file it is already a string.

Comment: i should convert this string : `10401A8C0` , to ip address

Comment: Then edit your post as now hex to string is nonsense. Please tell exactly which output it should give.

Comment: @greenapps , i have updated it .

Comment: No. It should convert  0401A8C0 i think. Please tell EXACTLY which ip address this is.

Comment: @greenapps sorry you are right , my error while typing

Comment: `get IP address from String`. A strange formulation as the string contains already the ip address. Only in hexadecimal representation. And you want it in .... decimal representation in four bytes.

Comment: @greenapps this is the string IP:PORT `0401A8C0:D366` that is displayed from proc/net/arp , can you help me how to parse to real IP:PORT

Comment: You are telling me nothing new. And you are not confirming that that string contains the ip address in hexadecimal represantation. If we cannot talk with each other in a normal way ... If you cannot agree that your subject is not to the point...

Comment: This string contains the ip address : `0401A8C0` maybe i sholud convert to byte[] {'04','01','A8','C0'} and than get it by `InetAddress addresses = InetAddresses.fromLittleEndianByteArray(byte);` , sorry for my low english

Answer (score 0):

I have solved it by converting the string : `0401A8C0` to byte array :

```
public static byte[] hexStringToByteArray(String s) {
    int len = s.length();
    byte[] data = new byte[len / 2];
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i += 2) {
        data[i / 2] = (byte) ((Character.digit(s.charAt(i), 16) << 4)
                + Character.digit(s.charAt(i+1), 16));
    }
    return data;
}
```

And than get IP address by :

```
InetAddress addresses = InetAddresses.fromLittleEndianByteArray(byte[]);
```